# player movement not working correctly in unity2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my game , the up and down movements are working fine , but the right and left are not working .

here is my code , any help would be appreciated.

```
   transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < maxY)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + increment);
        transform.position = targetPos;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > minY)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - increment);
        transform.position = targetPos;

    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x > minX)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.x + increment);
        transform.position = targetPos;

    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x > minX)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.y, transform.position.x - increment);
        transform.position = targetPos;

    }
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: when i press right key it goes up not going right side and not showing any movements after first time , same for left key it goes down and stopped working

Comment: Please add such information to the question by editing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are increasing and decreasing only the y part of Vector2 in last two else if part.

For going right your code should be like this :

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x <maxX)
    {
        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + increment, transform.position.y );
        transform.position = targetPos;
    }
```

and for left :

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x > minX)
{

    targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x - increment, transform.position.y);
    transform.position = targetPos;

}
```

Comment: There probably should be "< maxX" instead of "> minX" somewhere.

Comment: Yes you are right when you go right it should be transform.position.x < maxX

Comment: the mistake was just silly , and i'm just a beginner at this game development , but you guys helped me to solve the problem thank you guys .